# Sprite constantly moving when shouldn't

Tags: java, input, libgdx

I'm new to LibGDX and game making. The sprite keeps moving upwards EVEN when `Keys.UP` is not being pressed. Not too sure why this is happening as I am trying to get it to move only in response to `Keys.UP` being pressed.

I'm making my own inputprocessor class which will handle all inputs to the game, rather than each class handling the same things. My main class calls player.update(delta time) every frame thanks to the render method.

Why is it constantly moving up even when `Keys.UP` isn't being pressed? Shouldn't it fail at the conditional below? (GameInputProcessor is the instance `gip`)

Player class:

```
public void update(float dt){

    if (gip.keyDown(Keys.UP)){
        this.position.y += this.velocity * dt;
    }
```

GameInputProcessor class:

```
public boolean keyDown(int keycode){
    switch(keycode){

    case Keys.UP:
        System.out.println("up being pressed");
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually testing the key state.

```
gip.keyDown(Keys.UP)
```

will always return true for this code.

you want the code to look like

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)) 
    this.position.y += this.velocity * dt;
}
```

If you want the gdx class wrapped then modify the GIP to be

```
public boolean keyDown(int keycode){
    return Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(keyCode)
}
```

Comment: I was doing this, but this means I'll have to put it in my player class, which I don't want to do, I want to have this handled in GameInputProcessor class.

But then it needs to have a copy of the player instance from the main class where it was originally made. I'm not too sure how to give this to the GameInputProcessor class.

Comment: Great thanks that worked. For OO design, is that a good idea to do? Have every class working on only class specific things?

Comment: It is good to wrap things if you might want to replace it in the future. Then you just rewrite the wrapper and in theory everything still works. I like interfaces and use them a lot.